# Dynamic array of Years

Tags: php, array, datetime

I wanted to make a dynamic `select` statement from this year to 10 years. This gets the job done, but I feel like it's a little much.

```
 form_dropdown('year', array_combine(range(date('Y'), date('Y')+10), range(date('Y'), date('Y')+10)), set_value('year'));
```

Specifically, is there a better way to create this array, other than this?

```
array_combine(range(date('Y'), date('Y')+10), range(date('Y'), date('Y')+10))
```

Desired output (at least for this year):

```
Array
(
    [2014] => 2014
    [2015] => 2015
    [2016] => 2016
    [2017] => 2017
    [2018] => 2018
    [2019] => 2019
    [2020] => 2020
    [2021] => 2021
    [2022] => 2022
    [2023] => 2023
    [2024] => 2024
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get the output that you wanted, using `array_combine` will most likely be your best bet. You can simplify your statements pretty easily because variables are you friends:

```
$current_year = date('Y');
$date_range = range($current_year, $current_year+10);

form_dropdown('year', array_combine($date_range, $date_range), set_value('year'));
```

### Addendum by @brettsantore

I think this solves what I thought to be a problem, the combining of so many functions. I ended up simplifying it a little more.

```
$current_year = date('Y');
$range = range($current_year, $current_year+10);
$years = array_combine($range, $range);
```

Comment: I apologize for adding to your answer, but found writing that as a comment would have been absurd.

Answer (score 2):

***(I'm leaving the original answer intact for posterity, but please read the edit at the bottom of the answer as the answer is wrong).***

Why create a complicated line of code, such as:

```
array_combine(range(date('Y'), date('Y')+10), range(date('Y'), date('Y')+10))
```

When you can do a simple for-loop, such as:

```
$current_year = date('Y');
$max_year = $current_year + 10;
for($i = $current_year; $i <= $max_year; $i++){
    $year_array[$i] = $i;
}
```

Well - speed. The one liner mixture of `array_combine()`, `range()` and `date()` is multiple times faster than the for-loop. Not to mention that it creates less work for the GC.

I ran the two pieces of code above and this was the output:

```
$start_0 = microtime();
$year_array = array_combine(range(date('Y'), date('Y')+10), range(date('Y'), date('Y')+10));
$end_0 = microtime();

$start_1 = microtime(true);
$current_year = date('Y');
$max_year = $current_year + 10;
$year_array = array();
for($i = $current_year; $i <= $max_year; $i++){
    $year_array[$i] = $i;
}
$end_1 = microtime(true);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($year_array);
echo "0 Time: " . ($end_0 - $start_0) . "<br>";
echo "1 Time: " . ($end_1 - $start_1) . "<br>";
echo "</pre>";
```

[image: Benchmark of the two pieces of code]

Now, even if we make use of inlining the function calls, it gets even worse! See:

```
$start_0 = microtime();
$year_array = array_combine(range(date('Y'), date('Y')+10), range(date('Y'), date('Y')+10));
$end_0 = microtime();

$start_1 = microtime(true);
$year_array = array();
for($i = date('Y'); $i <= date('Y') + 10; $i++){
    $year_array[$i] = $i;
}
$end_1 = microtime(true);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($year_array);
echo "0 Time: " . ($end_0 - $start_0) . "<br>";
echo "1 Time: " . ($end_1 - $start_1) . "<br>";
echo "</pre>";
```

[image: Benchmark of the two pieces of code, inlining date()]

So, the best option is to go the `array_combine(), range(), date()` route. However, we can further optimize it as:

```
$start_range = date('Y');
$range = range($start_range, $start_range + 10)
array_combine($range, $range)
```

That way, we end up with 2 function calls to `date(), range()` and 2 new variables (which are cheaper than a function call), but is still not as performant as your original one liner.

```
$start_0 = microtime();
$year_array = array_combine(range(date('Y'), date('Y')+10), range(date('Y'),, date('Y')+10));
$end_0 = microtime();

$start_1 = microtime(true);
$year_array = array();
for($i = date('Y'); $i <= date('Y') + 10; $i++){
    $year_array[$i] = $i;
}
$end_1 = microtime(true);

$start_2 = microtime(true);
$start_range = date('Y');
$range = range($start_range, $start_range + 10);
array_combine($range, $range);
$end_2 = microtime(true);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($year_array);
echo "0 Time: " . ($end_0 - $start_0) . "<br>";
echo "1 Time: " . ($end_1 - $start_1) . "<br>";
echo "2 Time: " . ($end_2 - $start_2) . "<br>";
echo "</pre>";
```

[image: Benchmark of the three pieces of code]

My recommendation would be to keep your one liner.

***EDIT: My recommendation is you do #2 as I missed microtime(true) on `$start_0` and `$end_0`, thus I completely misread the benchmark output (which would make the one liner the slowest of the three tests). Thank you for catching that @Brett Santore.***

Comment: It appears you ran test 0 without `microtime(true)`, with 1.09E-5 or (0.0000109) < .0001. Wouldn't that support test 2 being faster with only 3 function calls?

Comment: Ah drats. Yeah, you're right. Tests 1 and 2 are increasingly faster by a near 10x magnitude: http://i.imgur.com/JZEi3PY.png

Comment: I added an edit at the top and bottom clarifying the incorrectness of the answer. I also left the original answer intact for posterity.